# What do i need to wrap a PL/SQL-Package in GitLab CI/CD?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, continuous-integration

I am trying to learn some more about GitLab CI/CD and wanna write a specific Stage like "wrap_packages", where a specific list of .sql-Files is given and these scripts should be wrapped to .plb, to copy&paste them into a specific folder.

Everything is working so far, but now i have to implement the wrapping. I guess i have to use an image, with Oracle Middleware, to use the wrap-command? Or is there a better way to do this? Because i cant find anything that helps me with this.

I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The wrap utility either exists in the full OCI client installation (not instant client), or within the actual database as an API. The simplest way to wrap your code is using the database API, after it is installed, as demonstrated here: https://github.com/pmdba/code-obfuscation-toolkit. There are a variety of ways that this could be incorporated into your CI/CD pipeline.

If you're looking for a more robust commercial (licensed $$$) solution, consider PCFLObfuscate (http://www.petefinnigan.com/products/pfclobfuscate.htm). It has a command-line option that integrates well with CI/CD.

A question that must also be asked is *why* you want to obfuscate your code with "wrap"? At best obfuscation only slows down someone who wants to see your code, as it is rather easily undone (at least the wrapping part). Deeper obfuscation (as provided by PFCLObfuscate, for example) actually changes the formatting of your code, your variable names, etc. before wrapping to make it much harder to tell what is going on even after it is unwrapped.

It is important to understand that there is no level of protection available for PL/SQL that can prevent someone with access to the wrapped code from unwrapping it and seeing the actual PL/SQL.